# How to determine whether I need to use a collection or a sub-collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app has 2 types of users - **businesses** and **customers**.
An each **business** has a **line** and **users** can get in it.

1. I'm not really sure whether it's better to create a sub-collection called "**tickets**" per each business with *customerId* or to have a separate collection "tickets" with corresponding *customerId* and *businessId*.
   I don't think that I'll ever need an opportunity to select all tickets at once.
   But I'm sure that I will have a dashboard where I want a customer to see all available lines and see how many people in there.
2. Also like I said I have 2 types of users - **customers** and **businesses** and probably their profile info is gonna be different.
   So, I guess it's better to have them **separate** rather than having a field like *userType*, right?

I'll attach a rough schema I created to better understand what data I need to store.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you prefer it tbh. If you go with first approach i.e. creating a dedicated collection to add the tickets then I'm assuming a part of your document will look something like:

```
{
  customerID: "customerID",
  businessID: "businessID",
  customerType: "typeOfCustomer",
  createdAt: 1624178545493
}
```

The benefit of doing this is you can create varieties of queries such as get tickets of a particular customer, business or user type or tickets in a specific time period.

Adding tickets of a particular business in it's own sub-collection looks organized but then if you want to query all tickets of a specific user and the user has tickets in multiple businesses, it'll be harder. You may have to store IDs of businesses where a user has open tickets.

In my *opinion*, a dedicated collection may offer you flexible queries in long run.

You can use the following security rules so a user can see his/her tickets only.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tickets/{ticketID} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly you can write rules for businesses and other docs easily. You can read more about Firestore Security Rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
As far as I know firebase has a collection group type of query. So, it basically means that it is not a problem to get all user tickets by creating a collection group query, isn't it?
Also, I'm concerned about security  - isn't it gonna be quite complicated to create security rules to restrict access of a business to tickets, so that business can only see his tickets and no other ones?

Comment: @VadimSheremetov not at all. Check my updated answer it contains the rules that you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding tickets of a particular business in it's own sub-collection looks organized but then if you want to query all tickets of a specific user and the user has tickets in multiple businesses, it'll be harders.

Comment: specific user and the user has tickets in multiple businesses