# Flutter how to get firestore subcollection id

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have my 'likes' arranged in a way that the document will have the post Ids and the collection will have all the user ids that have liked the post.

How can the collection id be read?  Like how to read 5WC2..., 6oWz... as an array or something.

I tried something like below but it is obviously not correct.

```
final likes = db.collection('likes').doc(post.id);
       print(likes.get());
```

It prints out Instance of 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a list of collections (or sub-collections) as stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document) unless you use the Admin SDK.

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries.

If you still need to do that with client SDK, then you would have to store an array of IDs of sub-collections in that document itself. Whenever a new sub-collection is added you can add it's ID using ArrayUnion and remove when a sub-collection is deleted using ArrayRemove method.

Although I'd recommend restructuring the database a bit. You can just have a root level collection called "likes" and have documents with the following structure:

```
{
  userID: "userUID",
  postID: "postID",
  likedAt: 1625297174856
}
```

This way you can query:

1. Posts liked by a specific user
2. Users who have a liked a specific post

Also you can sort them easily based the timestamp so it's much more convenient. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054070/how-to-determine-whether-i-need-to-use-a-collection-or-a-sub-collection/68054141#68054141) for another similar use case.